# Anonymous (?) initialization of a struct passed as an argument in C++03

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, anonymous

Say, I have

```
struct Foo
{
    char a;
    char b;
};

void bar(Foo foo);
```

What's the most succinct way to initialize a struct and pass it to the function? Ideally I would like to write something like

```
bar(Foo = {'a','b'});
```

What if Foo was a union?

UPD: My sincere apologies, the question was supposed to be in relation to C++03 only. Also, in this particular case, going away from POD is to be avoided (the code is for embedded system, ergo shorter bytecode is sought after). vonbrand, thanks for the C++11 answer.

Comment: Even better, just `bar({'a', 'b'});`.

Comment: In this case, I suspect that even for C++11 there will be ambiguity if the bar was overloaded.

Comment: Yes, there might be depending on how you overload it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ 11 you can write:

```
bar({'a', 'b'});
```

or:

```
bar(Foo{'a', 'b'});
```

(see Stroustup's [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init)).

g++-4.8.2 accepts this without complaints only if you give it `-std=c++11`, clang++-3.3 gives an error unless `-std=c++11`

Comment: Thank you. Please see the edit to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a constructor to your struct. e.g.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(char a, char b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    char a;
    char b;
};
```

Then you could call your function

```
bar(Foo('a', 'b'));
```

If it was a union, you could have different constructors for the different types of the union.

Comment: This is true but now your struct is no longer POD so it has huge ramifications. The C++11 way allows it to remain POD.